# Selecting item in databound combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, databound

I believe this question is kinda new-bie, but I can't solve it in correct way.

Brief description:

1. I have an inherited from ComboBox class that does some data bindings in constructor:

```
    var mdl = new Model();

    ValueMember = "id";
    DisplayMember = "unit";
    DataSource = mdl.getUnits();
```

All good here. The combobox is filled by required data.

1. Then I have another form with a function editIngridient. The function is following;

```
    public bool editIngridient(int id)
    {
    currentId = id;

    var row = mdl.getIngridient(id);

    txtIngridient.Text = (string)row["ingridient"];
    cmbUnit.ID = (int)row["unitId"];
    numNotifyQty.Value = (int) row["notifyQty"];

    ShowDialog();

    return true;
    }
```

1. Now, when the form popups, textbox and number box filled by needed values, while combobox is filled by first value.
2. If I will run the combobox data bind function as the first line inside editIngridient function - all works good.

Please point me to my stupidity.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the code button in the editor to outline the code in your question. You will get much more response that way.

Comment: If I will change function editIngridient in such way:

`var row = mdl.getIngridient(id);`
`Show();`
`txtIngridient.Text = (string)row["ingridient"];`
`cmbUnit.ID = (int)row["unitId"];`
`numNotifyQty.Value = (int) row["notifyQty"];`

It works.

Comment: Another update.

If I will set private variables in editIngridient function of unitId, ingridient and notifyQty, and in event Form_Load, I will assign controls values by the private vars set in editIngridient - all works good.

So, why I can't assign control(combobox) value directly in editIngridient function?

Answer (score 0):

YOu didnt say what is your dataSource, but I assume thats DataTable, so you can do it:

```
DataRowView rowData = comboBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
int id = Convert.ToInt32(rowData["id"]);
string name = rowData["unit"].ToString();
```

Comment: I believe you got me wrong. I need to select an item in data-bound combobox. Combobox is filled by rows from DataTable. That works.

The problem is that when I open the form in which this combobox placed, and before I run ShowDialog, I set the values of textboxes and this Combobox. Values of textboxes are set. But when I run combobox.SelectedValue = 3, and form appears, Combobox has first value selected.