# KendoComboBox normal autocomplete behavior not working when databound subscribed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui, databound, kendo-combobox

I have a project here that wasn't developed by me.
The project technologies: ASP.NET MVC, jQuery, Bootstrap and KendoUI.
And, it has a little problem.

The KendoComboBox autocompletes the text with the JSON datasource text while you are typing. This is perfect!
But if you subscribe the DataBound event to handle it, this autocomplete doesn't work correctly. It erases what you're typing. And this cause some rage in users.

This Window is the same to create a New Resgister and also to Edit some existing register...
So, the subscribed DataBound does the work to select one item in the ComboBox when editing.

And, the normal behavior of the ComboBox have to autocomplete when typing if we're creating a new one.

This is the New Window. The Autocomplete doesn't work with DataBound subscribed:
[image: Create a New One - I want autocomplete ON]

This is the Edit Window (the same, but, loaded).
[image: Edit a selected one - Works with DataBound]

If I remove the DataBound, the autocomplete of the ComboBox works fine:
[image: AutoComplete working]

This my HTML:

```
<div class="k-field">
    <div class="k-fieldlabel">Responsável:</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: calc(100% - 100px);">
        <input type="text" id="cboResponsavel" name="Responsavel.Id" style="width: 100%;" required validationmessage="Responsável é obrigatório" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In my document.ready function I have:

```
$("#cboResponsavel").kendoComboBox({
dataTextField: "Nome",
dataValueField: "Id",
dataSource: {
    type: "json",
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        total: "total"
    },
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/Projeto/Projetos/CarregarResponsaveis",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    }       
},
filter: "contains",
suggest: true,
dataBound:function(e){
    e.sender.value(@(Model == null ? "null" : Model.Responsavel.Id.ToString()))
}
});
```

My research:

[KendoCombobox is not fetching Localsource jsondata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746379/kendocombobox-is-not-fetching-localsource-jsondata)

[Kendo UI Demos - ComboBox / Basic Usage](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/combobox/index.html)

[Kendo UI Docs - ComboBox - Events - DataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#events-dataBound)

[KendoUI and json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998612/kendoui-and-json)

[kendo ui: how to remove a dataItem of a dataSource bound to some comboBox, inside combobox dataBound event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288141/kendo-ui-how-to-remove-a-dataitem-of-a-datasource-bound-to-some-combobox-insid)

[Selecting item in databound combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335787/selecting-item-in-databound-combobox)

I looked some posts in [Kendo UI Fórum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui-web) too.

I've updated jQuery and KendoUI and still persists...

I am pretty new to KendoUI and I had just fixed some ASP.NET MVC projects, so, I don't know how to fix this issue for now. Please, if someone can help or give me a direction, I will be thankful.

Oh, yeah, I want to fix others Combos with the same problem...

P.S.: If I select a value clicking on it, I can work here, but this is not productive.

I hope I made myself clear enough. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You say that if you remove the `dataBound` it works fine but did you try leaving it there but empty? Did you check what is the generated JS code (I mean, verify that the `e.sender.value...` looks like you expected. Try also invoking `e.sender.value("some literal")` in the dataBound and see if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotcha this error!

The solution is too idiot as me... haha

We, actually, doesn't need that event.

Here is the code that does the same:

```
$("#cboResponsavel").kendoComboBox({
dataTextField: "Nome",
dataValueField: "Id",
dataSource: {
    type: "json",
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        total: "total"
    },
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/Projeto/Projetos/CarregarResponsaveis",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    }
},
filter: "contains",
suggest: true,
value: @(Model == null ? "null" : Model.Responsavel.Id.ToString())
});
```

The behavior is working fine for New ones and it brings me the value in Edit mode.

The comment made by [Onabai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802671/onabai) was useful to discover that the DataBound event was not the problem, but trying to set the Value on it.

The solution was change the DataBound for Value, and it works fine!

Hope this help someone else (even this is simple).

Comment: Thank you very much mate! I've just ran into the same problem. I still believe that dataBound should work also, since the data is only bound once on the client side. The event should not be fired each time one activates the combobox. Moreover I found out that it seems to work dataBound too, but only if you enter your text very quickly into the combobox. Odd behaviour this is...